# Mysql query error

Tags: php, mysql

How do i make this code not to give error if he query is empty?

```
$ititle = 'test5';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, url, MATCH (title, url) " .
    "AGAINST ('test5') AS score FROM interlinks " .
    "WHERE MATCH (title, url) AGAINST ('test5') " .
    "AND title <> 'test5' LIMIT 20");

while ($irow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ||  ) 
{
    echo $irow["title"];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

TY!

Comment: Your code is missing the right operand for the `||` operator.

Comment: The error you're encountering would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ||, so it will just output nothing if the query is empty. It hould not give an error, other than a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error in your code:  You have an OR operator (||) but nothing coming after it.

Also, look into using [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check if your query has any results before looping (though it is perfectly fine to loop without the check--you will never get inside of the loop).